# Jest cannot find module sometimes

Tags: javascript, testing, jestjs, nestjs

actually i'm trying to test a function and getting that error:

[image: error]

Files that i'm using:

**searchUserService**

```
import { SearchUserService } from '../../src/service/searchUser.service';
import { SearchUserRepository} from '../../src/repository/searchUser.repository'
import { Util } from 'src/util/util'

let userId = '123456'

describe('', () => {
  it('', async () =>{

  const res =  new SearchUserService(new SearchUserRepository(new Util)).searchCredential(userId) 

    expect(res).toBe('')
})
})
```

**package.json**

```
    {
"scripts": {
"prebuild": "rimraf dist",
"build": "nest build",
"format": "prettier --write \"src/**/*.ts\" \"test/**/*.ts\"",
"start": "nest start",
"start:dev": "nodemon",
"start:debug": "nest start --debug --watch",
"start:prod": "node dist/main",
"lint": "tslint -p tsconfig.json -c tslint.json",
"test": "node_modules/.bin/jest --config jest.conf.js --detectOpenHandles",
"test:watch": "jest --watch",
"test:cov": "jest --coverage",
"test:debug": "node --inspect-brk -r tsconfig-paths/register -r ts-node/register node_modules/.bin/jest --runInBand",
"test:e2e": "jest --config ./test/jest-e2e.json"
},
"dependencies": {
"@nestjs/common": "6.7.2",
"@nestjs/core": "6.7.2",
"@nestjs/platform-express": "6.7.2",
"axios": "0.19.2",
"lodash": "4.17.15",
"reflect-metadata": "0.1.13",
"rimraf": "3.0.0",
"rpc-proxy": "^1.0.7",
"rxjs": "6.5.3",
"swagger-ui-express": "4.1.3",
"typescript": "3.6.3"
},
"devDependencies": {
"@nestjs/cli": "6.9.0",
"@nestjs/schematics": "6.7.0",
"@nestjs/swagger": "4.2.7",
"@nestjs/testing": "6.7.1",
"@types/express": "4.17.1",
"@types/jest": "24.0.18",
"@types/node": "12.7.5",
"@types/supertest": "2.0.8",
"dotenv": "8.2.0",
"jest": "24.9.0",
"nodemon": "2.0.2",
"prettier": "1.18.2",
"supertest": "^4.0.2",
"ts-jest": "24.1.0",
"ts-node": "8.4.1",
"tsconfig-paths": "3.9.0",
"tslint": "5.20.0",
"yamljs": "0.3.0"
}
}
```

**searchUser.service.ts**

```
  import { Injectable } from '@nestjs/common';
  import { BaseService } from '********************';
  import { SearchUserRepository } from '../repository/searchUser.repository';

  @Injectable()
  export class SearchUserService extends BaseService {
   constructor(private readonly searchUserRepository: SearchUserRepository) {
    super();
 }

async searchCredential(userId: string) {

  this.logger.info(`[SearchUserService] - searchCredential - userId = ${userId}`, '');

  return await this.searchUserRepository.searchCredential(userId);
}
}
```

**jest.conf.js**

```
        const path = require('path');

    module.exports = {
    rootDir: path.resolve(__dirname, './'),
    verbose: true,
    preset: 'ts-jest',
    testEnvironment: 'node',
    collectCoverage: true,
    coverageDirectory: process.env.JEST_CLOVER_OUTPUT_DIR || './_devops/coverage',
    coverageReporters: ['text', 'clover', 'lcov'],
    collectCoverageFrom: [
        '**/src/**/*.{ts}',
        '!**/spec/**/*.{ts}',
        '!**/tests/**/*.{ts}',
    ],
    moduleFileExtensions: [
        'ts',
        'tsx',
        'js',
        'json',
        'jsx'
    ]
    };
```

I've tried with another functions and debug, when i start the debug, the error instantly happens doesn't give any chance, with another functions I get the same.

it appears to be an Import error from Jest or NestJs.

I've checked the documentation of Jest and some Issues that appears to be same as i'm getting, but non of them resolved my problem.

Comment: `import { Util } from 'src/util/util'`
is an absolute path, and you might have a different root for the tsconfig and jest, which is the problem. You can try using a relative path to quick fix the issue: `import { Util } from '../../util/util'` (or something like that)